# Parallel background on all page Bootstrap

Tags: html, css

I want this background on my project like this:

[image]

Comment: No answer and just negative? haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is easily achieved using CSS [linear-gradient()](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-images/#linear-gradients)s:

```css
body {
  --gridColor: #eee;
  --gridSize: 10px;
  background-image:
    linear-gradient(to right, var(--gridColor) 10%, transparent 10%),
    linear-gradient(to bottom, var(--gridColor) 10%, transparent 10%);
  background-size: var(--gridSize) var(--gridSize);
}
```

See also Lea [Verou's CSS patterns](https://leaverou.github.io/css3patterns/) for more elaborate designs.